# Is there a windowed setting option for the Go compiler?

Tags: windows, console, gtk, go

I'm using Go (6g) to compile a GTK application and I want to know if there is a compiler/linker option to make it a Windows executable as opposed to console executable. MinGW has a -mwindows option for this and currently I'm having to manually alter the PE header with a hex editor which is annoying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> `-ldflags` 'flag list'    arguments to pass on each 5l, 6l, or 8l linker
>   invocation
>
> [Compile packages and dependencies](http://golang.org/cmd/go/)
>
> `-Hwindowsgui` (only in 6l/8l)    Write Windows PE32+ GUI binaries
>
> [Command ld](http://golang.org/cmd/ld/)

Add `-ldflags -Hwindowsgui` to the `go build/get/install` command line. For example,

```
go build -ldflags="-Hwindowsgui" gtkapp.go
```

Answer (score 1):

The old answer does not work for me. This works:

```
go build -ldflags -H=windowsgui gtkapp.go
```