# How do I create an executable from Golang that doesn't open a console window when run?

Tags: console, go

I created an application that I want to run invisibly in the background (no console). How do I do this?

(This is for Windows, tested on Windows 7 Pro 64 bit)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a windowed setting option for the Go compiler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391975/is-there-a-windowed-setting-option-for-the-go-compiler)

Comment: @kostix When I did a search for having no console, it didn't show up. But the flag you're pointing to is in that answer, you're right, I think, although the syntax is still slightly different and I wasn't looking for a "windowed option".

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The documentation found online says I can compile with something along the lines of,

`go build -ldflags -Hwindowsgui filename.go`

But this gives an error: `unknown flag -Hwindowsgui`

With more recent (1.1?) versions of the compiler, this should work:

`go build -ldflags -H=windowsgui filename.go`

When I continued searching around I found a note that the official documentation should be updated soon, but in the meantime there are a lot of older-style example answers out there that error.

Comment: From: https://golang.org/cmd/link/  `On Windows, -H windowsgui writes a "GUI binary" instead of a "console binary."`

Comment: Hi, do you know what flag would achieve the same on macOS and linux?

Answer (score 45):

Using Go Version 1.4.2

```
 go build -ldflags "-H windowsgui"
```

> *From the Go docs:*
>
> ```
> go build [-o output] [-i] [build flags] [packages]
> ```
>
> `-ldflags 'flag list'` arguments to pass on each 5l, 6l, or 8l linker invocation.

- [go build documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/go/)
- [ldflags docs](https://golang.org/cmd/ld/)

Comment: Don't forget you might need to include your `filename.go` as a parameter. In v1.10.1 the following syntax also works; `go build -ldflags -H=windowsgui filename.go`.

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to type the long build instructions every time during debugging but still want the console window to disappear, you can add this code at the start of your main function:

```
package main

import "github.com/gonutz/w32/v2"

func main() {
    console := w32.GetConsoleWindow()
    if console != 0 {
        _, consoleProcID := w32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(console)
        if w32.GetCurrentProcessId() == consoleProcID {
            w32.ShowWindowAsync(console, w32.SW_HIDE)
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can compile with `go build`. Your program will show the console window for a short moment on start-up and then immediately hide it.