# Create Golang executable that doesn't open a terminal window on OSX?

Tags: macos, go

How do you create a Golang executable that doesn't open a terminal window on OSX?

There's a similar question here for Windows.
[How do I create an executable from Golang that doesn't open a command (cmd) window when run?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23250505/395461)

Comment: I would believe that what matters is how do you start that executable (since MacOSX is a Unix or POSIX system). Very probably, if you start it as a `cron` job, it wont need any terminal. And if you start it on the command line, in an existing terminal, it probably won't open a new terminal window.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch What about when double clicking the executable in Finder? Is it supposed to open a Terminal window then?

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10067295/841108)

Comment: Would running as a daemon be suitable if the application has a GUI built with Electron?

Comment: I have no idea (since I never coded for MacOSX). On POSIX systems, programs are started by running the [execve](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) function -it is often a [syscall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call)-, and there is no reason for it to start a window. The Finder is just a graphical user interface, you could avoid it.

Comment: I don't think avoiding finder is the answer for me. I'm building an application for the public, so it really needs to behave like a regular Mac OSX application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87443/discussion-between-shannon-and-basile-starynkevitch).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23870490/395461

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, you just need to pack your executable in [application bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundle_%28OS_X%29#OS_X_application_bundles). It's just a directory with `.app` extension where executable, resources and configs (plist-files) are stored.

You can read all specs at [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html). Also you can open bundles with your existing apps and look what's inside.