# How to hide console window of a Go program on Windows

Tags: go

I tried various ways of creating a Go program that only displays either a `MessageBox` or a standalone GUI window.
If I were to write this in C / C++ I would just define a [`WinMain`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871617/winmain-and-main-in-c-extended), leave out the main and I would be good to go.
It seems to me that as soon as I define a `main` function a console window is created automatically. And the main function is compulsory.

```
package main
func main() {
...
}
```

To avoid this I tried an [example](https://github.com/ohisama/win/blob/master/win.go) which creates a WinMain

```
func WinMain(wproc uintptr) {
    hInstance := GetModuleHandle(nil)
    ...
}
```

But the effect is the same: an empty console window *and* a GUI window:
[image]

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Add `-ldflags -H=windowsgui` to your go build/install command line. You'll see that the console window is absent:

[image]

Comment: when I call `go build -ldflags -Hwindowsgui guionly.go` I get `flag provided but not defined: -Hwindowsgui`

Comment: Looks like I forgot the `=` sign there. See edited answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't see the missing `=`. And what's even worse: _now_ I was able to find a similar question that was asked before ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250505/how-do-i-create-an-executable-from-golang-that-doesnt-open-a-command-cmd-wind

Comment: this works for https://github.com/inkyblackness/imgui-go-examples, too