# How to create an astilectron application hiding the initial console

Tags: go, electron

I'm creating an application with astilectron on windows, but when I double click on the "*.exe" it start a console (see the image below) [image]

how can I hide this initial console window?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but https://stackoverflow.com/a/36728885 should solve your problem